# Prove that the sequence $\frac{x}{n}$ converges uniformly to 0 on each bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

I didn't get it right but here is my idea.
I know that $ f_n \rightarrow f  $ is uniformly converges if $ \forall \epsilon > 0$
$\exists \mathbf{N} \in \mathbf{Z}^{+} $ such that $\forall n > N, \forall x \in E,|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$

So I took any $(a,b)$ interval
$$ |\frac{b}{n} - \frac{a}{n}| < \epsilon $$
$$ n > |\frac{b-a}{\epsilon}| $$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$n>N>|\frac{b-a}{\epsilon}|$$
so it's uniformly converges but why it's uniformly converges to $0$?

Comment: You don't make much sense. First figure out  what $f$ should be and then write down what you have to prove.

Comment: "uniformly converges to $0$" means, that limit function $f=0$.

Comment: @lasha. For uniform convergence we need limit from $\sup |f-f_n|$ to be zero. Try, and write addition to your question how far have you gotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of uniform convergence is correct but it seems your proof attempt has strayed from that definition, and I am not quite sure what to make of it. Here is an attempt to guide you in the right direction.

Let $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, non-degenerate interval. Let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to find and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]$ and for all $n\geq N$, we have $$|f_n(x)-0|=\left|\frac{x}{n}\right|<\varepsilon$$

Well, if $a\leq x\leq b$, then we also have $$-|a|\leq a\leq x\leq b\leq |b|$$ If we define $M=\max\left\{|a|,|b|\right\}$, then we would have $-M\leq x\leq M$ hence $|x|\leq M$. Notice that $M$ cannot be $0$, since if it were, then we would have, say $0=|a|$, so $0=|a|\geq |b|\geq 0$ which would imply $a=b=0$. But this is a contradiction since $[a,b]$ is a non-degenerate interval.

Now we would need to find and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$, we have $$\left|\frac{x}{n}\right|\leq\frac{M}{n}<\varepsilon$$

You should be able to finish from here using the Archimedean Property.

**Edit**: As Matrin R has pointed out, this argument can made complete by assuming that $[a,b]$ is a bounded interval and simply defining $M=\max\{|a|,|b|\}+1$ to take care of the case when $[a,b]$ is degenerate. The cases when the interval takes on the form $(a,b], (a,b), [a,b)$ are covered in the above argument as well.

Comment: If you define $M$ as $1 + \max\{|a|,|b|\}$ then you don't have to exclude the case of degenerate intervals.